# Pagnation not working on pages other than 1

Tags: php, mysql, class, pdo, pagination

I am having an issue with a pagination script that I found on the internet but can no longer find the exact one.

The issue is that clicking the previous/next or any page number on the menu does not show the next set of values, presumably the LIMIT OFFSET in my SELECT statement isn't doing as it should, but I am unsure as to why. `jobs.php?action=listActiveJob&page=1&ipp` (ipp being in thr paginator lcass below as 5), this show the first 5 as expected, when clicking next or page 2 for example the URL changes to `jobs.php?action=listActiveJob&page=2&ipp=5` but the same 5 results are shown.

**jobs.php contains a lot of code that control several pages, but here is the code that controls this list**

```
function listActiveJob() { 
  $results = array();
  $data = Job::getActiveList();
  $results['activejobs'] = $data['results'];
  $results['totalRows'] = $data['totalRows'];
  require( TEMPLATE_PATH . "/job/listActiveJob.php" );
}
```

**In anouther file(Job.php), here is the code for `$data = Job::getActiveList();`**

```
  public static function getActiveList() {
    $conn = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD );

    $pages = new Paginator;
    $pages->items_total = 50;
    $pages->paginate();

    $sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS job_code, job_id, job_status, job_quoteid, job_contactid, job_companyid, job_schedulestatus, job_schedulestatus2, job_schedulestatus3
            FROM jobs WHERE job_status='Active'
            ORDER BY job_id DESC ".$pages->limit;

    $st = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $st->execute(); 
    $list = array();

    while ( $row = $st->fetch() ) {
      $job = new Job( $row );
      $list[] = $job;
    }
    $sql = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS totalRows";
    $totalRows = $conn->query( $sql )->fetch();

    $conn = null;
    return ( array ( "results" => $list, "totalRows" => $totalRows[0] ) );
  }
```

**the list is then in listActiveJob.php and is a simple foreach**

```
<?php foreach ( $results['activejobs'] as $job ) { 
 //BLA BLA LIST
}?>
```

**here is the code at the bottom of listActiveJob.php to show and control the pagination.**

```
  <?php 
    $pages = new Paginator;
    $pages->items_total = $results['totalRows'];
    $pages->paginate();
  ?>
  <p><?php echo $pages->display_pages();?></p>
  <p><?php echo '<span class="paginationbox" style="\"margin-left:25px;\""> '. $pages->display_jump_menu() . '</span>'; ?></p>
```

**and here is paginator.class.php**

```
<?php
class Paginator{
    var $items_per_page;
    var $items_total;
    var $current_page;
    var $num_pages;
    var $mid_range;
    var $low;
    var $high;
    var $limit;
    var $return;
    var $default_ipp = 5;

    function Paginator()
    {
        $this->current_page = 1;
        $this->mid_range = 25;
        $this->items_per_page = (!empty($_GET['ipp'])) ? $_GET['ipp']:$this->default_ipp;
    }

    function paginate()
    {
        if(isset($_GET['ipp'])){
          if($_GET['ipp'] == 'All')
          {
              $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->default_ipp);
              $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
          }
          else
          {
              if(!is_numeric($this->items_per_page) OR $this->items_per_page <= 0) $this->items_per_page = $this->default_ipp;
              $this->num_pages = ceil($this->items_total/$this->items_per_page);
          }
        }
        $this->current_page = (int) isset($_GET['page']); // must be numeric > 0
        if($this->current_page < 1 Or !is_numeric($this->current_page)) $this->current_page = 1;
        if($this->current_page > $this->num_pages) $this->current_page = $this->num_pages;
        $prev_page = $this->current_page-1;
        $next_page = $this->current_page+1;

        if($this->num_pages > 10) 
        {
            $this->return = ($this->current_page != 1 And $this->items_total >= 10) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?$_GET[action]&page=$prev_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\"> << Previous</a>    ":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\"><< Previous</span> ";

            $this->start_range = $this->current_page - floor($this->mid_range/2);
            $this->end_range = $this->current_page + floor($this->mid_range/2);

            if($this->start_range <= 0)
            {
                $this->end_range += abs($this->start_range)+1;
                $this->start_range = 1;
            }
            if($this->end_range > $this->num_pages)
            {
                $this->start_range -= $this->end_range-$this->num_pages;
                $this->end_range = $this->num_pages;
            }
            $this->range = range($this->start_range,$this->end_range);

            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($this->range[0] > 2 And $i == $this->range[0]) $this->return .= " ... ";
                // loop through all pages. if first, last, or in range, display
                if($i==1 Or $i==$this->num_pages Or in_array($i,$this->range))
                {
                    $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page And $_GET['page'] != 'All') ? "<a title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" title=\"Go to page $i of $this->num_pages\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=$_GET[action]&page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
                }
                if($this->range[$this->mid_range-1] < $this->num_pages-1 And $i == $this->range[$this->mid_range-1]) $this->return .= " ... ";
            }
            $this->return .= (($this->current_page != $this->num_pages And $this->items_total >= 10) And ($_GET['page'] != 'All')) ? "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=$_GET[action]&page=$next_page&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">Next >></a>\n":"<span class=\"inactive\" href=\"#\"> >> Next</span>\n";
            $this->return .= ($_GET['page'] == 'All') ? "<a class=\"current\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"#\">All</a> \n":"<a class=\"paginate\" style=\"margin-left:10px\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=$_GET[action]&page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";
        }
        else
        {
            for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
            {
                $this->return .= ($i == $this->current_page) ? "<a class=\"current\" href=\"#\">$i</a> ":"<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=$_GET[action]&page=$i&ipp=$this->items_per_page\">$i</a> ";
            }
            $this->return .= "<a class=\"paginate\" href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=$_GET[action]&page=1&ipp=All\">All</a> \n";
        }
        $this->low = ($this->current_page-1) * $this->items_per_page;
        if(isset($_GET['ipp'])){$this->high = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? $this->items_total:($this->current_page * $this->items_per_page)-1;}
        if(isset($_GET['ipp'])){$this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";}
    }

    function display_items_per_page()
    {
        $items = '';
        $ipp_array = array(10,25,50,100,'All');
        foreach($ipp_array as $ipp_opt)    $items .= ($ipp_opt == $this->items_per_page) ? "<option selected value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n":"<option value=\"$ipp_opt\">$ipp_opt</option>\n";
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Items per page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=$_GET[action]&page=1&ipp='+this[this.selectedIndex].value;return false\">$items</select>\n";
    }

    function display_jump_menu()
    {
        for($i=1;$i<=$this->num_pages;$i++)
        {
            $option .= ($i==$this->current_page) ? "<option value=\"$i\" selected>$i</option>\n":"<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
        }
        return "<span class=\"paginate\">Page:</span><select class=\"paginate\" onchange=\"window.location='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=$_GET[action]&page='+this[this.selectedIndex].value+'&ipp=$this->items_per_page';return false\">$option</select>\n";
    }

    function display_pages()
    {
        return $this->return;
    }
    }
    ?>
```

I hope I have explained this well enough and greatly appreciate any help getting me in the right direction

Comment: I don't see where you're using `:numRows` or `:job_id` in the query/queries.

Comment: Yeah to be fair they are redundant now and I haven't updated the script to reflect that, the issue though is only to do with pagination not the data the Select stament collects

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `.$pages->limit` in your sql statement in `public static function getActiveList()` adds the MySQL Limit statement to your query. However, I don't see where and how it's created in your code above. Since you're always returning the same data set, you might want to have a look there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It's created in paginator.class.php here `if(isset($_GET['ipp'])){$this->limit = ($_GET['ipp'] == 'All') ? "":" LIMIT $this->low,$this->items_per_page";}`